# Simple html dom and php fetch hidden content

Tags: php, regex, simple-html-dom

I am using [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) parser to fetch some data. Everything works great but I am facing a problem when I have enabled the **read more** plugin on my WordPress site.

The hidden content (the rest content of the article) is inside this `div`.

A sample:

```
<div class="mycontent">
Here is some content
<div class="brm" style="display: none;">
Here is another content but it's not vissible because the style of this div is set to display:none
</div>
<p><a href="#" class="brm-more-link">read more..</a></p>
</div>
```

So far I am using:

```
$url = "www.myurl.com";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$maindiv = $html->find('div.mycontent',0)->outertext;
```

it displays everything except the content inside the div `<div class="brm" style="display: none;">`

Any ideas how to get the hidden content?

Comment: The plugin probably uses Javascript to update the DOM. Simple HTML DOM can't execute Javascript.

Comment: Is `<div class="brm" style="display: none;">` inside `echo file_get_contents($url);` ?
Make sure the content you're trying to parse isn't generated by `JavaScript`, otherwise you won't be able to parse it using non `JavaScript` clients like `curl` or  `wget`, because the actual code isn't written on the `HTML` source  and it's rather generated in real time by the client `JavaScript` engine, normally a browser like chrome, firefox, etc.

Comment: I don't know html dom parsers very well. So, taking a stab in the dark here. It might be better to read the url source into a string variable, parsee the string to take out the offender, leaving `<div class="brm">`, then pass the string into whatever `$html->parsemethod($modified_html_string)`. That is if the dom accepts a string input.

Answer (score 0):

It actually does get that div:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$str = <<<EOF
<script type="text/javascript">
<div class="mycontent">
Here is some content
<div class="brm" style="display: none;">
Here is another content but it's not vissible because the style of this div is set to display:none
</div>
<p><a href="#" class="brm-more-link">read more..</a></p>
</div>
EOF;

$html = str_get_html($str);

echo $html->find('div.mycontent',0)->outertext;

// <div class="mycontent">  Here is some content  <div class="brm" style="display: none;">  Here is another content but it's not vissible because the style of this div is set to display:none  </div>  <p><a href="#" class="brm-more-link">read more..</a></p>  </div>
```